# Show that $(C^1([-1,1]),\|\cdot\|_{C^1})$ is not complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

> Let $C^1([-1,1])$ denote the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[-1,1]$. Define
> \begin{align*}
>   \|f\|_{C^1} = \left(\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 (|f|^2+|f'|^2)dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \quad \forall f\in C^{1}([-1,1]).
>  \end{align*}
> Show that $\|\cdot \|_{C^1}$ is a norm on $C^1([-1,1])$. If $(C^1([-1,1]),\|\cdot\|_{C^1})$ complete?

I am able to show that $\| \cdot \|_{C^1}$ is a norm and I choose the sequence of functions as $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}$ for $x \in [-1,1]$. I am also able to show this is a Cauchy Sequence. Now I want to prove that this sequence does not converge by contraction. Assume that it converges to some function $F$.

And I think that $F(x) = |x|$ so $F \not \in C^1[-1,1]$. So this Cauchy sequence is not a convergent sequence. But I'm not really sure to show that $F(x) = |x|$ properly (my professor said that saying something like $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = |x|,\quad \forall x \in [-1,1]$ is inappropriate).

Comment: Convergence in $C^1([-1,1])$ implies pointwise convergence. Hence, if the limit exists, then it must be $F(x)  = |x|$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: So you are saying that if $f_n$ converges to $F$ under the norm $\|\cdot\|_{C^1}$, then $f_n(x)$ converge to $f(x)$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$ right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all the normed and complete space, so I just want to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Apply $f(x)-f(0)=\int\limits_0^xf'(t)\,dt.$ Then $|f(x)-f(0)| \le \int\limits_0^1|f'(t)|\,dt\le \left (\int\limits_0^1|f'(t)|^2\,dt\right )^{1/2}\le \|f\|_{C^1}$

Comment: @hxllearnmath Yes for the first comment by yours. Its proof is given by Ryszard Szwarc's comment.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you explain more since what I want is that for each $x \in [-1,1]$, $|f_n(x)-F(x)| \leq \| f_n - F\|_{C^1}$, but based on what you gave me, isn't it $|f_n(x)-F(x) -(f_n(0)-F(0))| \leq \|f-F\|$?

Comment: Consider $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+n^{-2}}-n^{-1}.$ It is still a Cauchy sequence, but $f_n(0)=0.$